# Pass a Map into a method parameters of a xmlrpc server in java

Tags: java, python, xml-rpc

I want to create a `xmlrpc` server in java with a method that takes a parameter which is a Map. The server will be accessed by a python client,
This is the server code:

```
import org.apache.xmlrpc.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class JavaServer { 

 public static Object getData(Map <String, String> test){
//   Map <String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
//   hm.put("test", "result");
//   Object result = hm;
     return "ok";
 };

 public static void main (String [] args) {
  try {

     System.out.println("Attempting to start XML-RPC Server...");
     WebServer server = new WebServer(8080);
     server.addHandler("sum", new JavaServer());
     server.start();
     System.out.println("Started successfully.");
     System.out.println("Accepting requests. (Halt program to stop.)");
   } catch (Exception exception) {
     System.err.println("JavaServer: " + exception);
   }
  }
 }
```

The client code:

```
>>> import xmlrpclib
>>> proxy = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://localhost:8080/")
>>> proxy.sum.getData({"a":"b"})
```

I get the errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1224, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1578, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1264, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1297, in single_request
    return self.parse_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1473, in parse_response
    return u.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 793, in close
    raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
xmlrpclib.Fault: <Fault 0: 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: JavaServer.getData(java.util.Hashtable)'>

xmlrpclib.Fault: <Fault 0: 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: JavaServer.getData(java.util.Hashtable)'>
```

The same problem if I change to

```
public static Object getData(HashMap <String, String> test)
```

Comment: I think the problem is the method definition. Your method expects Map, but you are passing it a HashTable. Try changing it to HashTable

Comment: Same problem, I've updated my question

Answer (score 2):

I made a quick prototype locally. By the way, I am using Apache's XMLRPC library, because the one that you are using I think it is deprecated See [here](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/)

Okay, I made a quick prototype and brought the xmlrpc dependencies using maven.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>xmlrpc-testing</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlrpc-testing</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlrpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlrpc-common</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlrpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlrpc-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Java server class -- observe MyModel class, that can be changed with what you are using

```
import org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.server.PropertyHandlerMapping;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcServer;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcServerConfigImpl;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.WebServer;

import java.io.IOException;

public class XMLRPCServerMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws XmlRpcException, IOException {

        WebServer webServer = new WebServer(8080);
        XmlRpcServer xmlRpcServer = webServer.getXmlRpcServer();

        PropertyHandlerMapping phm = new PropertyHandlerMapping();

        phm.addHandler("MyModel", MyModel.class);

        xmlRpcServer.setHandlerMapping(phm);
        XmlRpcServerConfigImpl serverConfig =
                (XmlRpcServerConfigImpl) xmlRpcServer.getConfig();
        serverConfig.setEnabledForExtensions(true);
        serverConfig.setContentLengthOptional(false);

        webServer.start();
    }
}
```

Now here the most important thing to see, the definition of my `getData` method

```
public Object getData(Hashtable<String, String> data)
```

As I mentioned in the comment you should've tried to use `java.util.Hashtable`. 
I think it was a bit clear from the exception thrown:

```
xmlrpclib.Fault: <Fault 0: 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: JavaServer.getData(java.util.Hashtable)'>
```